# Define a color for \title, \address and \phone commands of a CV

Tags: color, moderncv

How can I define colors for a `moderncv` LaTeX file, for the following commands?

- `\address`
- `\title`
- `\phone`
- `\mail`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The colors of `moderncv` are controlled by `color0`, `color1` and `color2` (the last one being used for the elements you mention). You can redefine these as you like (example for cyan):

```
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,255}
```

Some predefined settings can be loaded through `\moderncvcolor`:

```
\moderncvcolor{blue}
```

where the argument can be `blue`, `orange`, `green`, `red`, `purple`, `grey` or `black`.

Finally, you could also use directly `\textcolor` in the argument of any moderncv command other than `\email`:

```
\phone{\textcolor{red}{123 456 7890}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\moderncvcolor` command allows you to define the color for headings.

```
\moderncvcolor{blue}  
% color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
```

There are several other parameters that you can control, for example the font.

```
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}        
% to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
```

You may consult the documentation and [examples](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) for further reference.